# retrieving data from arbitrary memory addresses using VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am working on developing a debugger plugin for visual studio using VSIX. My problem is I have an array of addresses but I cannot set the IDebugMemoryBytes2 to a particular address. I use DEBUG_PROPERTY_INFO and get the array of addresses, and I also am able to set the context to the particular addresses in the array using the Add function in IDebugMemoryContext2. However, I need to use the ReadAt function to retrieve n bytes from a specified address (from IDebugMemoryBytes2).

Does anyone have any idea how to retrieve data from arbitrary addresses from memory?

I am adding more information on the same:

I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio Extensibility package to build my debugger plugin. In the application I am trying to debug using this plugin, there is a double pointer and I need to read those values to process them further in my plugin. For this, there is no way to display all the pointer variables in the watch window and hence, I am not able to get the DEBUG_PROPERTY_INFO for all the block of arrays which the pointer variable is pointing to. This is my problem which I am trying to address. There is no way for me to read the memory pointed to by this double pointer.

Now as for the events in the debuggee process, since the plugin is for debugging variables, I put a breakpoint at a place where I know this pointer is populated and then come back to the plugin for further evaluation.

As a start, I was somehow able to get the starting addresses of each of the array. But still, I am not able to read x bytes of memory from each of these starting addresses.

ie., for example, if I have int **ptr = // pointing to something

I have the addresses present in ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2], etc. But I need to go to each of these addresses and fetch the memory block they are pointing to.

For this, after much search, I found this link: https://macropolygon.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/evaluating-debugged-process-memory-in-a-visual-studio-extension/  which seems to address exactly my issue.

So to use expression evaluator functions, I need an IDebugStackFrame2 object to get the ExpressionContext. To get this object, I need to register to events in the debuggee process which is for breakpoint. As said in the post, I did:

```
public int Event(IDebugEngine2 engine, IDebugProcess2 process, 
                 IDebugProgram2 program, IDebugThread2 thread, IDebugEvent2 
                 debugEvent, ref Guid riidEvent, uint attributes)
{
    if (debugEvent is IDebugBreakpointEvent2)
    {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

And my registration is like:

```
private void GetCurrentThread()
{
    uint cookie;
    DBGMODE[] modeArray = new DBGMODE[1];
    // Get the Debugger service. 
    debugService = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as 
                                                                IVsDebugger;
    if (debugService != null)
    {
        // Register for debug events.
        // Assumes the current class implements IDebugEventCallback2.
        debugService.AdviseDebuggerEvents(this, out cookie);
        debugService.AdviseDebugEventCallback(this);
        debugService.GetMode(modeArray);

        modeArray[0] = modeArray[0] & ~DBGMODE.DBGMODE_EncMask;

        if (modeArray[0] == DBGMODE.DBGMODE_Break)
        {
              GetCurrentStackFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to invoke the Event function at all and hence, I am not sure how to get the IDebugThread2 object.

I also tried the other way suggested in the same post:

```
namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("1DA40549-8CCC-48CF-B99B-FC22FE3AFEDF")]
    public interface IDebuggerInternal11 {
        [DispId(0x6001001f)]
        IDebugThread2 CurrentThread { [return: 
        MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] 
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = 
        MethodCodeType.Runtime)] 
        get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] 
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = 
        MethodCodeType.Runtime)] set; }
    }
}

private void GetCurrentThread()
{
    debugService = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger;
    if (debugService != null)
    {
        IDebuggerInternal11 debuggerServiceInternal = 
                       (IDebuggerInternal11)debugService;
        thread = debuggerServiceInternal.CurrentThread;

        GetCurrentStackFrame();
    }
}
```

But in this method, I think I am missing something but I am not sure what, because after the execution of the line

```
IDebuggerInternal11 debuggerServiceInternal = 
                                  (IDebuggerInternal11)debugService;
```

when I check the values of the debuggerServiceInternal  variable, I see there is a **System.Security.SecurityException** for CurrentThread, CurrentStackFrame (and so obviously the next line causes a crash). For this, I googled the error and found I was missing the **ComImport attribute** to the class. So I added that and now, I get a **System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

I am new to C# programming as well and hence, it is a bit difficult to grasp many things in short duration. I am lost as to how to proceed further now.

Any help in the same or suggestions to try another way to achieve my objective will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Esash

Answer (score 1):

After much search, since I am short of time, I need a quick solution and hence, for now, it seems like the quickest way to solve this problem is to hack the .natvis files by making it display all the elements of the pointer and then using the same old way by using IDebug* interface methods to access and retrieve the memory context for each of the pointer elements. But, after posting the same question in msdn forums, I think the proper answer to this problem is as mentioned by Greggs:
"For reading memory, if you want a fast way to do this, you just want the raw memory, and the debug engine of the target is the normal Visual Studio native engine (in other words, you aren't creating your own debug engine), I would recommend referencing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Engine. You can then use DkmStackFrame.ExtractFromDTEObject to get the DkmStackFrame object. This will give you the DkmProcess object and you can call DkmProcess.ReadMemory to read memory from the target."

Now, after trying a lot to understand how to implement this, I found that you could just accomplish this using :
DkmProcess.GetProcesses() and doing a ReadMemory on the process returned. 
There is a question now, what if more than one processes are returned. Well, I tried attaching many processes to the current debugging process and tried attaching many processes to the debuggee process as well, but found that the DkmProcess.GetProcesses() gets only the one from which I regained the control from, and not the other processes I am attached to. I am not sure if this will work in all cases but for me, it worked this way and for anyone who has similar requirements, this might work as well.

Using the .natvis files to accomplish this means, using IndexListItems for VS2013 and prior versions, and using CustomListItems for VS2015 and greater versions, and to make it look prettier, use the "no-derived" attribute. There is no way to make the Synthetic tag display only the base address of each variable and hence, the above attribute is the best way to go about, but this is not available in VS2013 and prior versions (The base address might get displayed but for people who want to go beyond just displaying contents and also access the memory context of the pointer element, Synthetic tag is not the right thing).

I hope this helps some developer who struggled like me using IDebug* interfaces. For reference, I am also giving the link to the msdn forum where my question was answered.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/030cef1c-ee79-46e9-8e40-bfc59f14cc34/how-can-i-send-a-custom-debug-event-to-my-idebugeventcallback2-handler?forum=vsdebug

Thanks.